# XML file to Json (org.json)

Tags: java, json, xml, org.json

I'm trying to convert XML to Json. 
I found this example bellow and works almost like the way I wanted. But, is there any way to load the XML file from my computer and not direcly from the code? I've found some alternatives but I would like to stick with org.json if possible...

`public static String TEST_XML_STRING = ("C:\\results\\results.xml")`; or something like that?

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class Main {


public static int PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR = 4;
public static String TEST_XML_STRING =

"<breakfast_menu>\n"+
"<food>\n"+
"<name>Belgian Waffles</name>\n"+
"<price>$5.95</price>\n"+
"<description>\n"+
"Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup\n"+
"</description>\n"+
"<calories>650</calories>\n"+
"</food>\n"+
"<food>\n"+
"<name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>\n"+
"<price>$7.95</price>\n"+
"<description>\n"+
"Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream\n"+
"</description>\n"+
"<calories>900</calories>\n"+
"</food>\n"+
"</breakfast_menu>";


public static void main(String[] args) {
try {JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(TEST_XML_STRING);

String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);

} catch (JSONException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}


}
}
```

I've got into this, but gives me error on line 20

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: at Main.main(Main.java:20)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class Main {

    File file = new File("teste.xml");
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] xmlData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    fin.read(xmlData);
    fin.close();

public static int PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR = 4;
public static String TEST_XML_STRING = new String(xmlData, "UTF-8");


public static void main(String[] args) {
try {JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(TEST_XML_STRING);

String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);

} catch (JSONException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}


}
}
```

Comment: The problem doesn't really have anything to do with Json/Xml, but reading files in java. Maybe you should change the title and description to reflect what the problem actually is.

Comment: I'm trying to use another plugin, BUT I'm still getting errors. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32829289/xml-to-json-jquery-plugin-not-working/32829475?noredirect=1#comment53495189_32829475

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FileInputStream` and get the file content into a `byte` array and pass it to `String` constructor to read the content from file.

```
File file = new File("yourdata.xml");
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] xmlData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
fin.read(xmlData);
fin.close();
String TEST_XML_STRING = new String(xmlData, "UTF-8");
```

NB: Another options is to open a `BufferedReader` and looping through calling `readLine()`.

**Update:**
Please use the below code, Procedural codes must be inside method/constructor/initializer block. They cannot be inside a class block.

```
public class Main {
    public static int PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR = 4;
    public static String TEST_XML_STRING = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("teste.xml");
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] xmlData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        fin.read(xmlData);
        fin.close();
        TEST_XML_STRING = new String(xmlData, "UTF-8");

        try {
            JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(TEST_XML_STRING);

            String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj
                    .toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
            System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: fin.read(xmlData);
fin.close(); 
are giving me errors: syntax and VariableDeclaratorId

Comment: please paste the stacktrace here.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at Main.main(Main.java:20)

Comment: @AdelM seems like there is an compilation error at Line 20 of Java class with name Main.
Unless you paste the whole stacktrace cant figure out what it is. 
Also what statement is in line 20 of the class Main?

Comment: its public static void main(String[] args) {} I'll post my whole code. its on my main post now

Comment: Yes that is required to help you, edit your question update the code and the error you are facing now.

Comment: It's on my main post now.

Comment: Thanks!! I'm new to the "throws IOException" gonna study that :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use java Reader to accomplish that.
example

```
Reader xmlSource = new FileReader("path/to/file.xml");
JSONObject json = XML.toJSONObject(xmlSource);
System.out.println(json);
```

you can read from url too...

```
URL url = new URL("http://xml");
Reader xmlSource = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
JSONObject json = XML.toJSONObject(xmlSource);
System.out.println(json);
```