# xml2json jQuery plugin not working

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, xml

I'm using the [jQuery XML to JSON Plugin by Fyneworks.com](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/).

Why this code isn't working?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="build/jquery.xml2json.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $.get('menu.xml', function(xml){
            var json = $.xml2json(xml);
            alert(json.message);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button>Menu List</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**menu.xml**

```
<xml>
 <message>Hello world</message>
</xml>
```

the error is : Uncaught TypeError: $.xml2json is not a function

Answer (score 1):

`jquery.xml2json.js` depends on `jquery`. So we have to load `jquery.js` first, and then `jquery.xml2json.js`.

```
<script src="build/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.xml2json.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to set the event handlers once the document is ready, you will want to use `on()` instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").on("click", function(){
        $.get('menu.xml', function(xml){
            var json = $.xml2json(xml);
            alert(json.message);
        });
    });
});
```

Otherwise, you will need to place this chuck of code **after** the element is created in the html, like so.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button>Menu List</button>

<script src="build/jquery.xml2json.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.get('menu.xml', function(xml){
           var json = $.xml2json(xml);
           alert(json.message);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $.xml2json is not a function